# Vapour absorption in 'normal conditions'

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

When is described: "In **normal conditions**, viscose absorbs 11 to 14% of water vapour. In liquid water, they swell and can absorb 80 to 120% of water." (Clothing Technology)

What do they mean with 'normal conditions'? In open air?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal or [standard conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure) are usually ment pressure of 101.325 kPa and temperature of 298.15 K or 293.15 K. Please see the link for reference.